# Unified login page for a Multisite/BuddyPress site

Tags: multisite

I use WordPress Multisite... and BuddyPress installed on the main site on mysite.com

Practically I want users to be automatically redirected to the main site login page every time they try to login from any of the blogs/sites/subdomains.

> *.mysite.com/login.php  =>  mysite.com/login.php

**Let me give some exemples:**

site1.mysite.com/wp-login.php redirected to mysite.com/wp-login.php

site2.mysite.com/wp-login.php redirected to mysite.com/wp-login.php

xyzkw.mysite.com/wp-login.php redirected to mysite.com/wp-login.php

.......................

*any future subdomain LOGIN PAGE - with no exceptions - will have to be redirected to mysite.com/wp-login.php*

Answer (score 1):

You could you do this with redirects through the root .htaccess  file;

Something like this perhaps:

```
# Redirect to new login

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

# For security reasons, Option followsymlinks cannot be overridden.

# Options +FollowSymLinks

Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain.mysite.com/login.php [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.subdomain.mysite.com/login.php [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.my-main-site.com/login.php/$1 [L,R=301]

</IfModule>

# Redirect end
```

Or to redirect all sub-domains to the parent, you could try this as a "catch all":

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^my-main-site\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://my-main-site.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Or if you want to exclude some sub-domains you could do this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^my-main-site\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^excluded-sub\.my-main-site\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://my-main-site.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

You'll have to have a play to get the login.php working.
This link may help:
http://www.scriptygoddess.com/archives/2007/06/13/redirect-a-subdomain-to-a-directory-using-htaccess/

Comment: Is this gonna redirect all my subdomains? I ask because this line looks strange: "RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain.mysite.com/login.php [OR]"! Maybe I din't make myself clear, I want all, like *.mysite.com redirect to...

Comment: I edited my answer above to add the catch all, hope that does it for you

Comment: Thank you I will test it, and get back to you, thanks :)

Comment: I don't want all my subdomains to redirect to the mainsite, I just want all the login pages to redirect to my mainsite login page... [ *.mysite.com/login.php => mysite.com/login.php ] If you know WP has a mysite/wp-admin for every blog/site in a network/multisite installation... and I don't want to customize every login page for every blog, just the one in the mainsite :) ... your code doesn't work for me, I need to customize it when I'll understand .htaccess scripting.